# Cycles Emissions

Tags: cycles-render-engine, emission

I have been trying to replicate a far-away sun between the two moons you see in the picture.
However, I cannot understand why this simple emission shader is producing no orange colour on the emission (no matter how strong I set it) but as you can see on the left moon an orange light is being generated.

might I have something wrong in my cycles setting?

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: it's not orange anymore precisely because its strength is very high, it will only remain orange if the strength is rather low (1, 2...), then it will get white

Comment: if you are going for physical accuracy, white is correct anyway, because the sun only appears orange because of earths atmosphere. =)  Of course you may not want that, just thought I'd mention in case.  =)  hope someone can help u get the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal behavior as color values climb above 1 (*Standard View Transform*) or 16~ (*Filmic View Transform*).

You need to use a volumetric shader or some other method to create a gradient where the center of the star is white and gradually fades out to your desired color at the corona.

Comment: Added a volumetric scatter node to the world shader and with some tweaking, it worked.  Thanks.  The result is in the link below.   https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=4088353794603911&set=a.145957295510267

Comment: @ronin074 nice one